# How to run PHP code in step-through mode with auto step after time for presentation purposes

Tags: phpstorm, step-into, step-through

For presentation purposes automatic step-into with time interval would be more comfortable in certain use-cases. It also could be nice tool for brief overview new applications. Do you know how to setup such function?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know anything that will step into code after a designated time period.

For a good overview on the whole debugging process in PHPStorm and what IS possible I would start with this...

[Webinar: Debugging PHP with PhpStorm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUTolQw8K9A)

If you are presenting the flow of the debugger through one of your applications you can use

```
# PhpStorm 7.1.1
View > Enter Presentation Mode
Alt + Shift + F9  # start debugging from your first breakpoint
```

You could also get familiar with the [Running and Debugging shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-2.html)

In my opinion these give you more control over your demonstration as they allow you to step into or skip over a function quickly you aren't interested in showing your friends.
This might be the case if you just want to show them YOUR specific code, as it will probably be more interesting and understandable than stepping through any 3rd party library functions that your code might use